# local json file and ng2-smart-table

Tags: json, angular, ng2-smart-table

How to load the local json file and display data in ng2-smart-table?

This is my current code for retrieve the data from the local json file:

```
public getList() {
    return this.http.get('./assets/data/line-items.json')
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
            console.log('data', json.items);
            return json.items;
        });
}
```

and I want to pass all the data to [source] in ng2-smart-table

```
<ng2-smart-table [settings]="settings" [source]="data"></ng2-smart-table>
```

Comment: what is the output of   `console.log('data', json.items);` ?

Comment: Array(50)
0:{id: 59, name: "...",  …}
1:{id: 53, name: "...",  …}
2:{id: 57, name: "...",  …}

Comment: your json looks good , can you show how you call `getList()` method ?

Comment: data = this.getList();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getList` return a promise, so you have to do this :

```
 this.getList().then(data=>{
   this.data = data;

});
```

Comment: I get it. Thank you so much for your help